# Aligning and stitching images based on defined feature using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I would like to create a panoramic image by combining 2 images in which the same feature, a plus sign.

I've used `cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` to find keypoints in the image however it doesn't find the plus symbol very well. Is there some way I can improve this by making it search specifically for a plus-shaped feature?

```
import cv2

image1 = cv2.imread('example_image.png')
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp = sift.detect(grey_image1, None)
kp_image = cv2.drawKeypoints(grey_image1, kp, None)

def showimage(image, name="No name given"):
    cv2.imshow(name, image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return

showimage(kp_image)
```

The source image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2dzb.jpg), second image to align is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O6GU.jpg). Here is the [resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO7iT.jpg) from the code above. This is an example of the [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO0We.jpg) made using GIMP and manually aligning the two images (the second image will need to transformed to fit properly).`

NB I'm open to using other approaches outside of OpenCV/Python to solve this problem.

Comment: Since the color of your plus sign isn't unique as background lines, so it wont be possible to perform color segmentation, IF the shape of your plus sign remains exactly consistent in all the snapshots, then you may try using [Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) after threshold input image to get the black color content.

Comment: @ZdaR Thanks for the comment. I'm taking photographs through a glass screen which I can mark to aide the stitching. After reading your comment I made some markings in red and green, I'll try to use a colour-based approach.

Comment: You could also try changing your current color space to another color space (HSV, Lab, Luv) and work on the (V, L and L) channels. The Intensity channel (V, L and L) in these color channels are robust to light changes. Probably that would give you better results.